# evaluate forecast by the terms of p-value and pearson correlation

Tags: r, correlation, p-value

I am using R to do some evaluations for two different forecasting models. The basic idea of the evaluation is do the comparison of Pearson correlation and it corresponding p-value using the function of cor.() . The graph below shows the final result of the correlation coefficient and its p-value.

[image]

we suggestion that model which has lower correlation coefficient with corresponding lower p-value(less 0,05) is better(or, higher correlation coefficient but with pretty high corresponding p-value).
so , in this case, overall, we would say that the model1 is better than model2. 
but the question here is, is there any other specific statistic method to  quantify the comparison?

Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're working with time series data since you called out a "forecast".  I think what you're really looking for is backtesting of your forecast model.  From Ruey S. Tsay's "An Introduction to Analysis of Financial Data with R", you might want to take a look at his [backtest.R](https://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/introTS/backtest.R) function.

```
backtest(m1,rt,orig,h,xre=NULL,fixed=NULL,inc.mean=TRUE)
# m1: is a time-series model object
# orig: is the starting forecast origin
# rt: the time series
# xre: the independent variables
# h: forecast horizon
# fixed: parameter constriant
# inc.mean: flag for constant term of the model.
```

Backtesting allows you to see how well your models perform on past data and Tsay's backtest.R provides RMSE and Mean-Absolute-Error which will give you another perspective outside of correlation.  **Caution** depending on the size of your data and complexity of your model, this can be a very slow running test.

To compare models you'll normally look at **RMSE** which is essentially the standard deviation of the error of your model.  Those two are directly comparable and smaller is better.

An even better alternative is to set up training, testing, and **validation** sets before you build your models.  If you train two models on the same training / test data you can compare them against your validation set (which has never been seen by your models) to get a more accurate measurement of your model's performance measures.

One final alternative, if you have a "cost" associated with an inaccurate forecast, apply those costs to your predictions and add them up.  If one model performs poorly on a more expensive segment of data, you may want to avoid using it.

As a side-note, your interpretation of a p value as less is better leaves a little to be [desired] [quite right](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics/how-to-correctly-interpret-p-values).

> P values address only one question: how likely are your data, assuming a true null hypothesis? It does not measure support for the alternative hypothesis.